# Loading Zend-Framework Model in Phpunit Class

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

I want to call my zend-framework model and use there functions in `AuthenticationControllerTest.php` but I am getting error when i run it from terminal.

```
 - -MyZendproject
 - -application
    -model
     -testmodel
 - +public
 - -tests
   - aplication
     - controller
       - .AuthenticationControllerTest.php
```

Here is my `AuthenticationControllerTest.php` file

```
<?php
require_once `PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php`;

defined(`APPLICATION_PATH`)
        || define(`APPLICATION_PATH`, realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . `/../application`));

    // Define application environment
        defined(`APPLICATION_ENV`) || define(`APPLICATION_ENV`, `tests`);

        // Ensure library/ is on include_path
        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,
                array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . `../../../library`), get_include_path())));

        // Zend_Application
        require_once `Zend/Application.php`;

        $application = new Zend_Application(
                APPLICATION_ENV,
                realpath(APPLICATION_PATH .`configs/application.ini`)
        );
class AuthenticationControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
     public function testLoginRetriespLogin() {
      $testmodel = new Model_testmodel_Object();//my model
    }   
}
```

but when run it from terminal "phpunit AuthenticationControllerTest" it give me error:

> $ phpunit AuthenticationControllerTest
>
> ..FPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Model_testmodel_Object' not found in /var/www/versioned/pm160form/tests/application/controllers/AuthenticationControllerTest.php on line 146

Comment: Your code actually should produce some more errors because of the many [backticks (execution operators)](http://php.net/language.operators.execution) you use. Apart from that what you describe in your question is just a missing class definition. Just require the file which contains it.

Comment: Also I think you could benefit reading about the phpunit bootstrap file and xml configuration: http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your test suit folder is not resolving towards the actual application folder. See how you have

```
|| define(`APPLICATION_PATH`, realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . `/../application`));
```

but your dirname is currently pointing to the test/application/controller directory which, of course, does not have your actual application.  Try pointing the application folder that is under the top root instead,

```
|| define(`APPLICATION_PATH`, realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . `/../../../application`));
```

Also, take care to follow the standard of using PHP Unit in Zend Framework as described at http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.test.phpunit.html . The framework needs to be fully bootstraped before the autoloader can work.